# AWS ECS without ECR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, ecm

Does it make sense to use ECS without ECR? I ask this because it seems that ECM and ECR are very closely integrated.

From the sound of it, I might end up having to use a 3rd party registry with ecm.

I would like to know thoughts on this and maybe recommended strategies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you not want to use ECR when using ECS over ECM?

I am a certified cloud Architect and a DevOps engineer using ECS+ECR since about a year now. Below are the reasons why I think you should use the native combo.

1. Both Native to AWS - Single domain ownership
2. ECR provides the ability to have retention policies on your images
3. Gives you the ability to create custom IAM roles for access to your ECR repositories
4. ECR is an encrypted S3 bucket in the background - AWS give you the 99.99 SLA with the durability without you having to worry about it.

Thanks,
Vishal

Comment: This was my thought as well... We decided to use ECR on my recommendation.. But the entire team was confused because our certified cloud Architect was telling us that we should use private reg with ECS... being that I have used ECS, I knew that there were obvious advantages being that ECR functionality is integrated into ECS... Our "architect" was told that he is no longer a part of our project recently lol

Comment: Now one reason is that ECR doesn't support ipv6 and Amazon is charging for ipv4s